# What's wrong with my Laravel form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm trying to make a simple form on Laravel, but I don't know what's going wrong: info looks like it's not being sent from form to controller,

Please, could you help me?

Here's my route:

```
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@contact')->name('welcome');
```

Here is my Controller:

```
 class HomeController extends Controller
 {

 public function contact()
   {
       $text = "";
       $text .= "\r\n Contacto: ".request("senderName");
       $text .= "\r\n Web: ".request("senderWeb");
       $text .= "\r\n Teléfono: ".request("senderPhone");
       $text .= "\r\n Email: ".request("senderEmail");
       $text .= "\r\n\n\n".request("senderMessage");

       Mail::to(Config::value('contact_mail'))
             ->queue(new 
       ContactMail(request('name'),$text,request("senderEmail")));

       return view('welcome');
     }

 }
```

And here my form:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
<form name="contactform" id="contactForm" method="post" action="/">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
  <!-- senderName start -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <input name="senderName" id="senderName" class="input-md input-rounded form-control" placeholder="Nombre de la compañia"
      maxlength="100" required>
  </div>
  <!-- senderName end -->
  <!-- senderPhone start -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <input name="senderPhone" id="senderPhone" class="input-md input-rounded form-control" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="100"
      required>
  </div>
  <!-- senderPhone end -->
  <!-- email start -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <input type="email" name="senderEmail" id="senderEmail" class="input-md input-rounded form-control" placeholder="Email" maxlength="100"
      required>
  </div>
  <!-- email end -->
  <!-- email start -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <input name="senderWeb" id="senderWeb" class="input-md input-rounded form-control" placeholder="Web" maxlength="100" required>
  </div>
  <!-- email end -->
  <!-- email start -->
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <textarea name="senderMessage" class="form-control" rows="8" id="senderMessage" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
  </div>
  <!-- email end -->
  <!-- button start -->
  <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-right mt25" id="sendButton">
    {{--<button class="contact-button hover-fade">Enviar</button>--}}
    <p><input class="btn contact-button hover-fade" type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
  </div>
  <!-- button end -->
</form>
```

Seriously, I don't really know what's going wrong.

Comment: Your code works here. Any errors? If you do `dd($text);` it displays the info from the form?

Comment: I made dd($text) and nothing happens, for this reason I think the problem may be in the form

Answer (score 0):

You specified no action in your form 
Try adding the code

```
<form name="contactform" id="contactForm" method="post" action="{{route('welcome')}}"><form action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but deleting id and name from form header it worked!!

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('welcome')}}">
```